# remove duplicate from combo box connected to database

Tags: sorting, filter, combobox, distinct

I am trying to remove duplicates from a `Combobox`, however, this doesn't seem to result in a correct `Combobox`, since he fills the `Combobox` with the following text:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__64`1[System.Char]
```

I have the following code and am using an access database with generated datasets.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Generator
{
        private void matGroupBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.matGroupBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.matGroupDataSet);
        }
        private void frmImport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.matGroupTableAdapter.Fill(this.materialGroupDataSet.MatGroup);

            //Distinct
            var BaseM = materialGroupDataSet.MatGroup.Select(row => row["BaseMs"].ToString().Distinct());
            foreach (var BaseMs in BaseM)
            {
               cmbBaseMat.Items.Add(BaseMs);
            }

        }
```

I have 3 `Comboboxes` that I want to fill with data from the database. The `ComboBox1` is filled with data and then it removes the duplicates correctly.

However, when I select a value from the `ComboBox1`, it will update the `ComboBox2` with the possible choices based on the `ComboBox1` and if I select a value from the `ComboBox2` it fills the `ComboBox3` with resulting data.

I'm now first trying to filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found.

```css
cmbBaseMat.DataSource = materialGroupDataSet.MatGroup.Select(x => x.BaseMs).Distinct().ToList();
```

If anyone has a better solution please post it.